# Unable to run as TestNG in Eclipse Kepler or Luna on Mac machine

Tags: testng, eclipse

I am using Mac Yosemite 10.10.3 and Eclipse Kepler (4.3). I installed latest TestNG from the official site [testng.org](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) and added it successfully from Help menu but TestNG option is not showing under run as or under properties of the project.

Do I need to set the path of it or what else I can do to get this done?
Please help.
Thanks in advance.